# Find element by text in xpath not working - selenium webdriver

Tags: java, xml, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have noticed that function text() in order to find elements in xpath in selenium webdriver does not work in this case:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-labeled ng-binding" ng-click="ok()" type="button">
<span class="btn-label">
<i class="fa fa-check"/>
</span>
Selecionar
</button>
```

As you can see, the text 'Selecionar' is inside button tag, but after the text there are other tags, in this case when I try to find element by xpath using this pattern: //*[text()='Selecionar'] is finding no element.

Do you all know how do I find element button in this case, assuming using its text (because in other cases, it will be the only option)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the exact text match in this case since there are newline characters before the actual text. Use [`contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) or [`normalize-space()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space):

```
//button[contains(., 'Selecionar')]
//button[normalize-space(.) = 'Selecionar']
```